# Recursive Promises - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a recursive function setup to recreate/load a propertyTemplate array.

The first function is given an object like this:

```
 {   
    staffedLocation: ['schedulingGroup',{property: 'staff',subProperties: ['description']}],
    staff: true,
    assignedShifts: true,
    editedShifts: true,
    deletedShifts: true,
    unassignedShifts: true,
    rangeStart: true,
    rangeEnd: true
}
```

I need to recreate this object into an array of objects so as to properly populate my UI:

```
[
    {checked: null, name: "staffedLocation", properties: [
        {checked: null, name: "oid", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "integer"},
        {checked: null, name: "_class", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "string"},
        {checked: true, name: "schedulingGroups", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "list"},
        {checked: null, name: "staff", properties: [
            {checked: null, name: "oid", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "integer"},
            {checked: null, name: "_class", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "string"},
            {checked: true, name: "description", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "string"},
            {checked: null, name: "limits", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "list"},
            {checked: null, name: "weeklyMaxHours", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "integer"}

        ], toggle: true, type: "list"},
    ], toggle: true, type: "staffedLocation"},
    {checked: null, 
    name: "staff", properties: [
        {checked: null, name: "oid", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "integer"},
        {checked: null, name: "_class", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "string"},
        {checked: null, name: "description", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "string"},
        {checked: null, name: "limits", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "list"},
        {checked: null, name: "weeklyMaxHours", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "integer"}
    ], toggle: true, type: "staff"},
    {checked: null, name: "assignedShifts", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "shiftForEmail"},
    {checked: null, name: "editedShifts", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "shiftForEmail"},
    {checked: null, name: "deletedShifts", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "shiftForEmail"},
    {checked: null, name: "unassignedShifts", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "shiftForEmail"},
    {checked: null, name: "rangeStart", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "timestamp"},
    {checked: null, name: "rangeEnd", properties: null, toggle: null, type: "timestamp"}
]
```

Currently when I call the convert function, it walks through and begins creating my array of objects. However, when it hits the convertRecurse, a  promise is created to gather the properties for one of the items.

Initially I thought nesting everything within the promise would run the function properly after I'd gathered all of the properties. However, when I go to the page and load the template the first time, the properties do not appear. If I re-run opening the template again, it works.

I'm thought chaining the promises would cause the 2nd promise to wait to move on. However, I don't have the best understanding of how they work.

```
function convert(template){
    $scope.propertyTemplate = [];
    for(var k in template){
        var obj = {};
        obj.checked = null;
        obj.name = k;

        if(template[k] !== true){
            convertRecurse(template[k], obj, k);
        } else {
            obj.properties = null;
            obj.toggle = null;
        }

        $scope.propertyTemplate.push(obj);
    }
}

function convertRecurse(array, obj, parent){

    var propArr = [];

    var namespace = new namespaceFactory(parent);
    namespace.init();

    namespace.fetchProperties().then(function(props){
        props.forEach(function(prop){

            var fetchObj = {};
            fetchObj.name = prop.property;
            fetchObj.type = prop.type;
            fetchObj.checked = null;
            fetchObj.properties = null;
            fetchObj.toggle = null;

            propArr.push(fetchObj);
        });

        return propArr;

    }).then(function(){

        var objArr = [];

        for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){

            if(typeof array[j] === 'object'){
                objArr.push(array[j]);
                array.splice(j, 1);
                j--;
            }

            for(var i = 0;i < propArr.length; i++){

                if(array[j] === propArr[i].name){
                    propArr[i].checked = true;
                } 
            }
        }

        for(var k = 0; k < objArr.length; k++){
            var propObj = {};
            propObj.checked = null;
            propObj.name = objArr[k].property;

            if(objArr[k].subProperties){
                convertRecurse(objArr[k].subProperties, propObj, objArr[k].property)
                for(var x = 0; x < propArr.length; x++){
                    if(propArr[x].name === propObj.name){
                        propArr.push(propObj);
                        propArr.splice(x, 1);

                    }
                }
            } else {
                propObj.properties = null;
                propObj.toggle = null;
            }
        }

        obj.properties = propArr;
        obj.toggle = true;

    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
}
```

My issue is that when I initially call this function the first time, it doesn't load.

[image]

However, if I call it again, everything seems to work perfectly.

[image]

Comment: `obj.properties = propArr;` Where is `obj`?

Comment: The obj is passed in as part of the params

Comment: Outside of convertRecurse, how do you know when `obj.properties` is set? (Note that it will NOT be set the moment the function exits as the promise has yet to complete)

Comment: Could you open up a bit how you actually call `convertRecurse` and how you have to "call it again" to make it work. How do you expect it to function? This is also a bit confusing: "which should resolve and return propArr", as you then ignore the return value in the chained callback (though it works since `propArr` is created in the outer scope). The images are pretty useless without more information. The other just has more text.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I've updated my question. Hopefully it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: Much appreciated, now there's something to work with. One thing though: as @Katana314 pointed out, you're dealing with asynchronous operations when you bring in promises. As `convertRecurse` does not return a promise in itself, how do you know when the object pushed in `$scope.propertyTemplate.push(obj);` is properly populated (to me it would seem you cannot know)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I believe you are both correct in that I really cannot know. However, it seems odd to me that it appears to work fine after it's failed once. Do I need to make this call for getProperties to be synchronous then?

Comment: Though not sure how, I think the second call "succeeds" because the data has been fetched in between. What makes me unsure is that you do reset `$scope.propertyTemplate = [];` in the beginning of `convert`, so again we'd need a bit more scope to perhaps find out how the data, that has been fetched, is rendered before the second attempt. There might be no need for synchronous `getProperties`, you just have to rethink it a bit: `convert` and friends should return a promise that resolves when all the properties have been fetched and resolved etc. Code depending on the results would continue then.

Comment: @IljaEverilä correct, `$scope.propertyTemplate = [];` always gets reset in the convert function, but it is also gets reset from another function i have called closeTemplate. The close template function sets the `$scope.propertyTemplate = null`. I'll keep playing around with the convertRecurse. I appreciate all the help thus far though!

Comment: You might want to try boiling this down to its essence, a process described as creating a [mcve]. That might help you to see what's going on, without the distraction of the other things your script should be doing. In other words, try just having a recursive function, and use a promise within it. Throw some console.logs in there to see the order of actions. I think you can figure this out if you break it down. Good luck.

Comment: In both `convert()` and `convertRecurse()` you have async stuff in loops. You therefore need either to aggregate the promises created in the loops (eg. `Promise.all(array.map(...))`), or to sequentialise them (eg. `array.reduce(...)`). You also need to ensure that both functions return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having concerns asynchronous flow. The code as currently written treats `convertRecurse()` as synchronous, whereas it is actually asynchronous.

Code is difficult to follow in places but the tricky bits are synchronous transforms, which I've not attempted to understand.

The fixes are quite extensive, in part because asynchronous operations occur in loops. More specifically, you need either :

- to perform async operations sequentially by building a .then() chain, or
- to perform async operations in parallel and aggregate promises

As you'll see below, a major aspect of the asynchronous flow is making appropriate returns all through.

Here it is, adopting the sequential approach :

```
function convert(template) {
    $scope.propertyTemplate = [];

    // Make array of template's enumerable keys
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
    var keys = Object.keys(template);

    // Build a .then() chain from `keys`.
    return keys.reduce(function(promise, k) {
        return promise.then(function() {
            var obj = {
                name: k,
                checked: null,
                properties: null,
                toggle: null
            };
            if(template[k] !== true) {
                return convertRecurse(template[k], obj, k);
            } else {
                return obj;
            }
        }).then(function(obj_) {
            $scope.propertyTemplate.push(obj_);
            return obj_; // make obj_ available to the caller
        });
    }, $q.resolve()); // $q is assumed
}

function convertRecurse(array, obj, parent) {
    var namespace = ...
    return namespace.fetchProperties().then(function(props) {
        var propArr = ... // some synchronous transform of (props)
        var objArr = ... // some synchronous transform of (array, propArr)

        // Build a .then() chain from `objArr`
        return objArr.reduce(function(promise, o) {
            return promise.then(function() {
                if(o.subProperties) {
                    var propObj = {
                        name: o.property,
                        checked: null,
                        properties: null,
                        toggle: null
                    };
                    return convertRecurse(o.subProperties, propObj, o.property).then(function() {
                        propArr = ... // some synchronous transform of (propArr, propObj)
                    });
                }
            });
        }, $q.resolve())
        .then(function() {
            obj.properties = propArr;
            obj.toggle = true;
            return obj; // deliver the augmented obj back to the caller.
        });
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Barring mistakes on my part (not at all impossible), all you need to do is reinsert the code for the three transforms, which are omitted for clarity of the overall flow. Personally, I would write the transforms as functions and keep the code above much as it is.